# Optional named groups

Tags: php, regex

Currently I have `#([A-Z]+)\>*(.*)#` regex.
This is how it works:

```
URL>{B>{A>a}}

Array
(
    [0] => URL>{B>{A>a}}
    [1] => URL
    [2] => {B>{A>a}}
)
```

I need to make an optional named group at the end of capture, for example:

```
URL>{B>{A>a}}:value

Array
(
    [0] => URL>{B>{A>a}}
    [1] => URL
    [2] => {B>{A>a}}
    [name] => value
)

URL>{B>{A>a}}

    Array
    (
        [0] => URL>{B>{A>a}}
        [1] => URL
        [2] => {B>{A>a}}
    )
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does `:value` always begin with a colon?  Are there any more specific rules about it?

Comment: Yes, the value always starts with a colon. There are no more rules, just make named capture all after colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *name* a capture using the `(?P<name>group)` syntax.

For example:

```
/([A-Z]+)\>([^:]*)(?::(?P<name>\w+))?/
```

**Note:** This assumes all *values* start with a colon then contain only *word characters*. Adjust to meet you needs.

Comment: This will not capture anything because of the `(.*)`.  Why wrap it in `(?:`?

Comment: Good point about the greediness. See update. `(?:`, I assumed they did not want the colon.

Comment: I think you mean to use `(?::` then?

Comment: Colon can be only in the end, it will never be before, don't look on the (.*)